# Maximal ideals of the ring of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, modules, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let K be a field. We consider $K^n$ as a left module of $M_{n, n}(K)$, the ring of matrices of size $n$ over $K$.

1) For any $M_{n, n}(K)$ module homomorphism $ 0 ≠ \phi: M_{n, n}(K) \to K^n$, show that $ker\space \phi$ is always a maximal left ideal.

2) Also, for any maximal left ideal $I \in M_{n,n}(K)$, show that $M_{n,n}(K)/I \cong K^n$, and also show that there's a module homomorphism $\phi$ as described in 1) so that $ker\space\phi = I$.

Thanks in advance. I guess that these maximum ideals are of such shape that they have entries $\in K$ in each line except for just one, in which they only have zeroes? Because these sets of matrices seem to form left-ideals, and also seem to fit the description of maximal ideals, because when also filling the last line with entries $\in K$, they are equal to $M_{n,n}(K)$. But apart from that, I don't really know how to approach these questions.

Comment: "maximal ideal" should probably be "maximal left ideal"? In noncommutative (and commutative) algebra, the word "ideal" without qualifications like "left" or "right" in front of it usually means "two-sided ideal".

Comment: "I guess that these maximum ideals are of such shape that they have entries $\in K$ in each line except for just one, in which they only have zeroes" -- not quite, but in some sense. There is, for instance, a maximal left ideal which consists of all matrices whose rows sum to $0$.

Comment: Hint to the exercise: If $\phi$ is an $M_{n,n}\left(K\right)$-module homomorphism $M_{n,n}\left(K\right) \to K^n$, then $\phi$ is explicitly given by $\phi\left(A\right) = Av$, where $v \in K^n$ is the image of the identity matrix under $\phi$. Conversely, given any $v \in K^n$, you can define a $M_{n,n}\left(K\right)$-module homomorphism $\phi : M_{n,n}\left(K\right) \to K^n$ by $\phi\left(A\right) = Av$ for all $A$. If the $\phi$'s look too inconcrete to you, you can always work with the $v$'s instead.